# Technicality at multiplying fractions when solving inequalities?

Tags: inequality, fractions

I have a question when multiplying fractions in this case (assuming):  $$x>0$$

1.$$\frac{x+4}{3x+2}>\frac{1}{x}$$ $$\frac{x+4}{3x+2}-\frac{1}{x}>0$$ $$\frac{x^2+x-2}{x(3x+2)}>0$$
2.$$\frac{x+4}{3x+2}>\frac{1}{x}$$ $$x^2+4x>3x+2$$ $$x^2+x-2>0$$

Why can't I just simplify as in case 2.?Because if we had = instead of >, there would be no discussion what to do.  Obviously the right solution is 1.solving example. Why aren't both cases equivalent?

Comment: @saulspatz:  OP said assuming $x>0$ so $x(3x+2)>0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I completely missed that, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. If $\tfrac{x+4}{3x+2}>\tfrac1x$ then indeed $\tfrac{x^2+x-2}{x(3x+2)}>0$ and $x^2+x-2>0$.

Comment: The problem is that in 2.case we lose one part of expression =$$\frac{1}{x(3x+2)}$$

Answer (score 3):

Actually, approach 2. is OK, as long as you take care to keep in mind the assumption $x\gt0$ (which implies $2x+3\gt0$ as well).  The difference between the two approaches is easy to see if you write out *explicitly* the correct logical statements that are actually being made.  Here's approach 1.:

$${x+4\over3x+2}\gt{1\over x}\iff {x+4\over3x+2}-{1\over x}\gt0
\iff{x^2+x-2\over x(3x+2)}\gt0$$

And here's approach 2.:

$$\left(x\gt0\land{x+4\over3x+2}\gt{1\over x} \right)\iff\left(x\gt0\land x^2+4x\gt3x+2 \right)\iff\left(x\gt0\land x^2+x-2\gt0 \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Because $x>0$ we also have $x(3x+2)>0$ and hence
$$\tfrac{x^2+x-2}{x(3x+2)}>0
\qquad\text{ if and only if }\qquad
x^2+x-2>0.$$
So the two cases *are* equivalent, and both are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write $$\frac{x+4}{3x+2}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x^2+x-2}{x(3x+2)}$$
and you have to solve
$$\frac{(x-1)(x+2)}{x(3x+2)}>0$$
now you must ditinguish several cases:
1) $$x>1$$
2)$$-\frac{2}{3}<x<0$$
3)$$x<-2$$